# Illegal instance declaration for 'Monad (Writer String)'

Tags: haskell, monads

I've tried to create my own Writer type and afterwards I also made an instance for it. Anyway, I keep on getting this error:

```
Illegal instance declaration for ‘Monad (Writer String)’
  (All instance types must be of the form (T a1 ... an)
   where a1 ... an are *distinct type variables*,
   and each type variable appears at most once in the instance head.
   Use FlexibleInstances if you want to disable this.)
In the instance declaration for ‘Monad (Writer String)’
```

This is my code:

```
newtype Writer log a = Writer {runWriter :: (a,log)} 
instance Monad (Writer String) where
  return a = Writer (a, "")
  ma >>= k = let (a, log1) = runWriter ma 
                 (b, log2) = runWriter (k a)
             in Writer (b, log1 ++ log2)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> All instance types must be of the form (T a1 ... an)

...meaning, you could write

```
instance Monad (Writer a) where ...
```

but not

```
instance Monad (Writer String) where ...
```

because `String` is not a type variable.

This is just a silly restriction standard Haskell has had since Haskell98. Apparently, the restriction makes it easier to write a compiler, I don't know. Everybody uses the `FlexibleInstances` extension, which has been in GHC for ages and disables the restriction.

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
newtype Writer log a = Writer {runWriter :: (a,log)} 
instance Monad (Writer String) where
  ...
```

Alternatively, you could use the more polymorphic instance, but `Monad (Writer a)` doesn't quite work because you need to be able to have empty logs and concatenate logs. The standard solution is to invoke the generic class for concatenable types:

```
import Data.Monoid

instance Monoid a => Monad (Writer a) where
  return a = Writer (a, mempty)
  ma >>= k = let (a, log1) = runWriter ma 
                 (b, log2) = runWriter (k a)
             in Writer (b, log1 <> log2)
```

On another note, to have a `Monad` instance you must first also instantiate [`Applicative`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Control-Applicative.html).

Comment: Right, thanks! Now I'm getting this one.. :)) "No instance for (Applicative (Writer String))
      arising from the superclasses of an instance declaration
    In the instance declaration for ‘Monad (Writer String)’
"

Comment: Yeah, that's what I meant. You need to first define `instance Applicative (Writer String)` before you can have the monad instance.